# How can I add "note" below two tables put next to each other?

Tags: tables, threeparttable, rmarkdown

I use Rmarkdown and I am trying to put a note below two tables that I want them to appear next to each other. I manage to make appear them next to each other only when the "note" is not there. If I add the note, the tables appear one below the other and the note appear at the end of the second table.

This is the code in Rmarkdown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimated Wordscores in the Training Model}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
\label{tab: first}
  & $Hawkish$\\
\midrule
budget balance & $-0.21$\\
rebuild fiscal buffer &  $-0.71$\\
fiscal consolidation &  $-0.93$\\
get their house in order & $-0.22$\\
avoid any procyclical bias & $-0.21$\\
expenditure restraint & $-0.75$\\
budget retrenchment & $-0.21$\\
no case for fiscal activism  & $-0.21$\\
debt sustainability & $-0.70$\\
deficit reduction & $-0.82$\\
structural adjustment & $-0.82$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
  & $Dovish$\\
\midrule
domestic demand & $0.75$\\
fiscal space & $0.84$\\
government expenditure & $0.53$\\
job creation & $0.18$\\
flexibility & $0.24$\\
automatic stabiliser & $0.51$\\
public investment & $0.91$\\
public sector & $0.54$\\
fiscal union & $0.68$\\
growth friendly & $0.71$\\
ease social hardship & $0.86$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Note}: The table shows the estimated wordscores of the reference texts. A negative score means that the word is a fiscally hawkish word, while a positive score indicates a fiscally dovish one.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: Would it be an option to combine both `tabular` environments to just one? Or do you want to add individual captions later on? How is your question related to `beamer`? Is this the documentclass you use? If so, how did you manage to fit the two tables into the same frame?

Comment: @leandriis I added the missing info. It should be reproducible now. Sorry about it. Ideally I want a unique tabular with a unique note below. If you remove the necessary code for the note, you will get that the two table appear next to each other

Comment: I'd suggest using a single `tabular` with 4 columns instead of two tabulars with 2 columns each. Do you also want to keep the small gap in the horizontal lines? I have edited the tags and removed `beamer` since you don't seem to use it here.

Comment: @leandriis Right, I will try that. Beamer was useless indeed! Sorry

Comment: To make your code compilable, the `float` and `threeparttable` packages are missing.

Comment: @leandriis does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three slightly different versions of your table. Probably one of them suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimated Wordscores in the Training Model}
\begin{tabular}{lrlr}
\toprule
\label{tab: first}
  & Hawkish &   & Dovish\\
\midrule
budget balance & $-0.21$ & domestic demand & $0.75$\\
rebuild fiscal buffer &  $-0.71$ & fiscal space & $0.84$\\
fiscal consolidation &  $-0.93$ & government expenditure & $0.53$\\
get their house in order & $-0.22$ & job creation & $0.18$\\
avoid any procyclical bias & $-0.21$ & flexibility & $0.24$\\
expenditure restraint & $-0.75$ & automatic stabiliser & $0.51$\\
budget retrenchment & $-0.21$ & public investment & $0.91$\\
no case for fiscal activism  & $-0.21$ & public sector & $0.54$\\
debt sustainability & $-0.70$ & fiscal union & $0.68$\\
deficit reduction & $-0.82$ & growth friendly & $0.71$\\
structural adjustment & $-0.82$ & ease social hardship & $0.86$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Note}: The table shows the estimated wordscores of the reference texts. A negative score means that the word is a fiscally hawkish word, while a positive score indicates a fiscally dovish one.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimated Wordscores in the Training Model}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-1.2]lS[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
\label{tab: first}
  & {\textit{Hawkish}} &   & {\textit{Dovish}}\\
\midrule
budget balance & -0.21 & domestic demand & 0.75\\
rebuild fiscal buffer &  -0.71 & fiscal space & 0.84\\
fiscal consolidation &  -0.93 & government expenditure & 0.53\\
get their house in order & -0.22 & job creation & 0.18\\
avoid any procyclical bias & -0.21 & flexibility & 0.24\\
expenditure restraint & -0.75 & automatic stabiliser & 0.51\\
budget retrenchment & -0.21 & public investment & 0.91\\
no case for fiscal activism  & -0.21 & public sector & 0.54\\
debt sustainability & -0.70 & fiscal union & 0.68\\
deficit reduction & -0.82 & growth friendly & 0.71\\
structural adjustment & -0.82 & ease social hardship & 0.86\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Note}: The table shows the estimated wordscores of the reference texts. A negative score means that the word is a fiscally hawkish word, while a positive score indicates a fiscally dovish one.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimated Wordscores in the Training Model}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-1.2]@{\hspace{4\tabcolsep}}lS[table-format=1.2]@{}}
\toprule
\label{tab: first}
  & {\textit{Hawkish}} &   & {\textit{Dovish}}\\
\midrule
budget balance & -0.21 & domestic demand & 0.75\\
rebuild fiscal buffer &  -0.71 & fiscal space & 0.84\\
fiscal consolidation &  -0.93 & government expenditure & 0.53\\
get their house in order & -0.22 & job creation & 0.18\\
avoid any procyclical bias & -0.21 & flexibility & 0.24\\
expenditure restraint & -0.75 & automatic stabiliser & 0.51\\
budget retrenchment & -0.21 & public investment & 0.91\\
no case for fiscal activism  & -0.21 & public sector & 0.54\\
debt sustainability & -0.70 & fiscal union & 0.68\\
deficit reduction & -0.82 & growth friendly & 0.71\\
structural adjustment & -0.82 & ease social hardship & 0.86\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\item \textit{Note}: The table shows the estimated wordscores of the reference texts. A negative score means that the word is a fiscally hawkish word, while a positive score indicates a fiscally dovish one.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks a lot!